# Whether to choose WPF(browser application) or Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I dig into the WPF(browser app) and Silverlight application environment to know which one is best suitable for web development. I search out many portals saying that WPF is good for window forms and Silverlight for web. I also tested my WPF web app on different browsers and faced thousands of browser plugins issues except IE browser. As I come to know Silverlight is sub party of WPF which means SL has less features as compare to WPF. Now I want to figure out which practice is best suitable for web development and why?????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programming related Q&A site. Your question isn't belong here. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: WPF browser Application is not a Web technology as such. It is a WPF application with restricted functionality and very tight security settings (like accessing files and so forth) that requires the correct .Net Version on the target computer and runs in IE only. It is not a browser plugin like Silverlight. If you really want to develop web sites stick with Silverlight.

Comment: @SonerGönül And which site would be more proper to ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is being discontinued, so don't use it for anything important.  Use WPF if you want that kind of display tech, or Metro w/C# or Javascript